# Unable to load entites to database

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am developing a web application and I am using docker to create an image for my entire back-end. Right now I can create an image for the database, phpmyadmin and the app itself but the problem comes from not being able to load all entities in the database.

This here are my entities:

```
package org.example.persistence.entity;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ExerciseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    private String imageUrl;




}


package org.example.persistence.entity;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.example.domain.MessageStatus;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Data
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "messages")
public class MessageEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "sender_id")
    private Long senderId;

    @JoinColumn(name = "receiver_id")
    private Long receiverId;

    @Column(name = "message")
    private String message;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private LocalDateTime date;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status")
    private MessageStatus status;
}

package org.example.persistence.entity;

import lombok.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class RequestEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "exercise_id")
    private Long exerciseId;


    @Column(name = "reps")
    private Integer reps;

    @Column(name = "weight")
    private Double weight;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private LocalDate date;

}

package org.example.persistence.entity;

import lombok.*;
import org.example.domain.Role;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

@Entity
@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Length(min = 2 ,max = 50)
    private String email;

    @NotBlank
    private String password;

    @NotBlank
    private String firstName;

    @NotBlank
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "role", columnDefinition = "ENUM('CUSTOMER', 'TRAINER', 'ADMINISTRATION')")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;
}


package org.example.persistence.entity;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Entity
@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserExerciseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
    private UserEntity user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="exercise_id", nullable=false)
    private ExerciseEntity exercise;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private LocalDate date;
}
```

When I run the docker-compose and log in with phpmyadmin I can see only the user entity being created. This is my application.properties :

```
##spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3331/FitBuddy?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://host.docker.internal:3331/FitBuddy?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
#
#
#
#spring.datasource.username=root
#spring.datasource.password=pass123
###
#spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
#logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
#logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
#spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
#jwt.secret=E91E158E4C6656F68B1B5D1C316766DE98D2AD6EF3BFB44F78E9CFCDF5
#
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3331/FitBuddy?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/FitBuddy?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.username=Stoyan
#spring.datasource.username=Stoyan

spring.datasource.password=pass123
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.packagesToScan=org.example.persistence.entity

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

spring.jpa.open-in-view=false

jwt.secret=E91E158E4C6656F68B1B5D1C316766DE98D2AD6EF3BFB44F78E9CFCDF5
```

and this is the docker-compose:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: FitBuddy
      MYSQL_USER: Stoyan
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass123
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass123

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
    ports:
      - 7098:80

  app:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_PORT: 3306
      DB_USER: Stoyan
      DB_PASSWORD: pass123
      DB_NAME: FitBuddy
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

what could the problem be?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not being able to load all entities in the database"? Are you getting an error? wrongly loaded entities? Something else?

Comment: I just get the user entity the other entities are not present in the db

Comment: Can you show some logs that could help us understand what JPA does on startup?